# finding a derivative using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

suppose $g,f\in \mathcal{C}^2,:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
define $u(x,y)=xf(x+y)+y*g(x+y)+xy$

cumpute $$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+u_{yy}$$

I think im having some problems with the notation of the chain rule because of that (x+y)
i've managed to show that

1. $u_{xx}=2f_x+xf_{xx}+yg_{xx}$
2. $u_{yy}=2g_y+yg_{yy}+xf_{yy}$
3. $u_{xy}=f_y+xf_{xy}+yg_{xy}+g_x+1$
   but nothing cancels out so I'm pretty sure I have a problem with the notation

Comment: The star in $y∗g(x+y)$ is a multiplication? If so you can write just $yg(x+y)$ as you've done for $xf(x+y)$

Comment: Also, now I see you wrote $f_x$ and $f_y$ for partial derivatives of $f$ (and the same for $g$). But since $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ they don't have partial derivatives, only full derivatives. Therefore you can write just $f'$,$g'$, $f''$ and $g''$. This will possibly allow you to cancel out some terms, as yours $f_y$ and $f_x$ will be the same

Answer (score 2):

The notation $f_x$ is not correct since $f$ is a one variable function. Indeed, the partial derivatives of the composition $h(x,y)=f(t)\circ (x+y)$ are $$\frac{\partial f(x+y)}{\partial x}=f'(t)\circ (x+y)\cdot 1=f'(x+y)=h_x,\,\frac{\partial f(x+y)}{\partial y}=f'(t)\circ (x+y)\cdot 1=f'(x+y)=h_y,$$ same for $g$. Then $h_x=h_y$, $h_{xx}=h_{yy}=h_{xy}$, and the same holds for the composition $g(t)\circ (x+y) $, then from your calculations (but now with the correct notations) we have $$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+u_{yy}=2f'+xf''+yg''+2g'+yg''+xf''-2f'-2xf''-2yg''-2g'-2=-2.$$

Comment: I know, i explained that. $f_x$ refers to the partial derivative in $x$ of the composition $f(t)\circ (x+y)$, which is a two variable function.

Comment: That's right. Thanks, i edited it to avoid OP's confusion

Answer (score 0):

OPs derivation is fine. The usage of $f_x,f_y, g_x, g_y$ is adequate, since we consider $f(x+y), g(x+y)$ as functions in two *independent* variables $x$ and $y$.

Here we calculate the derivatives and look at a small example as plausibility check.

> We consider a function $u$
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}}\\
> &\color{blue}{u(x,y)=xf(x+y)+yg(x+y)+xy}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> and functions $f,g$
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}}&\color{blue}{g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}}\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{f(z)=z^3}&\color{blue}{g(z)=\frac{z}{2}}\\
> \end{align*}

At first we calculate $u_x,u_y,u_{xx},u_{xy},u_{uu}$ from (1). We use some parentheses that are not necessary, but they can help to better understand the derivations.

> We obtain using a compact notation
> \begin{align*}
> u_x&=\left(f+xf_x\right)+\left(yg_x\right)+y\\
> u_y&=\left(xf_y\right)+\left(1\cdot g+yg_y\right)+x\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{u_{xx}}&=f_x+\left(1\cdot f_x+xf_{xx}\right)+\left(yg_{xx}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2f_x+xf_{xx}+yg_{xx}}\tag{3.1}\\
> \color{blue}{u_{xy}}&=f_y+xf_{xy}+\left(1\cdot g_x+yg_{xy}\right)+1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+f_y+g_x+xf_{xy}+yg_{xy}}\tag{3.2}\\
> \color{blue}{u_{yy}}&=\left(x_{yy}\right)+\left(g_y+\left(1\cdot g_y+yg_{yy}\right)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2g_y+xf_{yy}+yg_{yy}}\tag{3.3}
> \end{align*}
> and observe we get the same result as OP.

**Example:** Now we calculate as small plausibility check the partial derivatives from $u=u(x,y)$ using $f,g$ as specified in (2). We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{u(x,y)}&=xf(x+y)+yg(x+y)+xy\\
&=x(x+y)^3+y\frac{1}{2}(x+y)+xy\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=x^4+3x^3y+3x^2y^2+xy^3+\frac{3}{2}xy+\frac{1}{2}y^2}\tag{4.1}
\end{align*}
We calculate the partial derivatives from (4.1) and obtain
\begin{align*}
u_x(x,y)&=4x^3+9x^2y+6xy^2+y^3+\frac{3}{2}y\\
u_y(x,y)&=3x^3+3y+6x^2y+3xy^2+\frac{3}{2}x+y\\
\\
\color{blue}{u_{xx}(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=12x^2+18xy+6y^2}\tag{5.1}\\
\color{blue}{u_{xy}(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=9x^2+12xy+3y^2+\frac{3}{2}}\tag{5.2}\\
\color{blue}{u_{yx}(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=9x^2+12xy+3y^2+\frac{3}{2}}=u_{xy}(x,y)\\
\color{blue}{u_{yy}(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=6x^2+6xy+1}\tag{5.3}
\end{align*}
Now we calculate $u_{xx}, u_{xy}$ and $u_{yy}$ using formulas (3.1) to (3.3). We obtain this time using full notation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{u_{xx}(x,y)}&=2f_x(x+y)+xf_{xx}(x+y)+yg_{xx}(x+y)\\
&=2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y)^3+x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(x+y)^3+y\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\\
&=2\cdot 3(x+y)^2+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(3(x+y)^2\right)+y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=6x^2+12xy+6y^2+3x\cdot2(x+y)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=12x^2+18xy+6y^2}\tag{$\to (5.1)$}\\
\\
\color{blue}{u_{xy}(x,y)}&=1+f_y(x+y)+g_x(x+y)+xf_{xy}(x+y)+yg_{xy}(x+y)\\
&=1+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+y)^3+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\\
&\qquad+x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}(x+y)^3+y\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\\
&=1+3(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{2}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(3(x+y)^2\right)+y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}+3x^2+6xy+3y^2+3x\cdot 2(x+y)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{2}+9x^2+12xy+3y^2}\tag{$\to (5.2)$}\\
\\
\color{blue}{u_{yy}(x,y)}&=2g_y(x+y)+xf_{yy}(x+y)+yg_{yy}(x+y)\\
&=2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(x+y)^3
+y\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\\
&=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(3(x+y)^2\right)+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=1+3x\cdot 2(x+y)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1+6x^2+6xy}\tag{$\to (5.3)$}
\end{align*}
and get the same results as in (5.1) to (5.3).